# Checking members and instantiating in properties

Tags: c#, design-patterns, object-oriented-design, patterns-and-practices

Consider this:

```
public MyClass
{
    private Resource _myResource;

    public Resource MyResource
    {
        get
        {
            if(_myResource == null)
            {
                _myResource = new Resource();
            }

            return _myResource;
        }
    }

    public void UseResource()
    {
        MyResource.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Is this a recognised pattern, or possibly an anti-pattern? I've never seen it suggested in any books, but it does come up time and time again in code I see. I think the logic of this is that _myResource is instantiated 'just in time'. To me, it seems a bit smelly. UserResource() is accessing a public property from within the class, and the resource can never really be accessed through the private member - if someone did, _myResource could be null.

Maybe performance reasons may sometimes necessitate, but I would generally favour instantiating in the constructor, or just having an instance of Resource local to the method.

So is this an accepted pattern, or should it be avoided?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this pattern but this particular example is quite a poor example. It would be better to pass an abstract factory into the constructor of the class, and query the factory the first time the resource is needed...

Comment: @MattDavey: You cannot say that universally. In many cases your suggestion would be just plain overengineering imho.

Comment: This seems to violate the Single Responsibility Principle. The class is already doing too much by creating and using the resource. Creation should be separated which would also make unit testing easier.

Comment: @c_maker: I strongly disagree! If all you have to do is calling a simple constructor, then you should not put the creation in its own class, for the sake of simplicity. Also, in this generic example, we cannot tell whether the SRP is really violated. It's perfectly fine for a class to create something that it will use.

Comment: @Falcon A class which is tightly coupled to its resource and calls the constructor directly is not cohesive, and is not unit testable. There's a distinction between consuming a resource, owning the lifetime of a resource and being responsible for constructing a resource...

Comment: @Matt Davey: I don't see the point here with this specific example (and many other uses of lazy initialization). So you'd replace the tight coupling on the resource with a possibly needless factory class? What if the resource creation is never subject to change by definition? To me that sounds a lot like overengineering and testability does not improve significantly.

Comment: @MattDavey: Find me in chat when you want to discuss it any further.

Comment: @Falcon I disagree, unit testing would *only* be possible by adding an indirection to the creation of the resource. As it is in the example, it would be *impossible* to unit test MyClass without also testing Resource - that's not unit testing, it's integration testing. Were Resource a private nested class not publicly exposed, you could label it a mere implementation detail in which case having MyClass own responsibility for its creation would make sense.

Comment: Thinking about it more, I'm guessing our disagreement comes down to the ambiguous nature of the word "resource". To me resource is a weighted term which implies a relatively complex procedure of creation & management (ie file handles etc), in which case I stand by my comments. Looking at the simple example here it could also represent something as simple as a 3 dimensional vector value, in which case I agree with everything you've said :)

Comment: My fault, I'm not sure why I chose the word 'resource', I've seen this pattern used for instantiating simple objects, but I think it should only be used for more complex external things like WCF channels, ADO connnections etc (although they should really both be in a using block)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an accepted pattern. It's called [lazy initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization), a [creational pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creational_pattern). You usually use this for performance reasons, often combined with other patterns, for example the [Proxy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern). When resources are heavy and you don't need them right away, then this is a good and clean approach to make sure they're only initialized the first time you need them.

Wikipedia calls it a "*tactic of delaying the creation of an object, the calculation of a value, or some other expensive process until the first time it is needed*".

ORMs for example use this pattern to perform lazy initializations of related entities, so you needn't fetch a whole aggregate object-graph eagerly, but only when you really need to operate on the related entities.

---

> Maybe performance reasons may sometimes necessitate, but I would
>   generally favour instantiating in the constructor, or just having an
>   instance of Resource local to the method.

Sure, this might be a cleaner approach. But if the resources are really costly to instantiate, then lazy initialization is a good way to deal with them. Do you really want to wait a long time for instantiating an object that by itself is lightweight, but occasionally needs a heavy resource?

> To me, it seems a bit smelly. UserResource() is accessing a public
>   property from within the class, and the resource can never really be
>   accessed through the private member - if someone did, _myResource
>   could be null.

It looks indeed a bit smelly and if it is used everywhere and not by its purpose then it really stinks. As with all optimizations: Don't optmize if you don't need an optimization. But lazy initialization can be a great benefit to your application when used right. And then its inconspicuous smell is a small price to pay for its worth.

Comment: Cheers for that. So I'll go with the common 'only do it if you can argue a case for it approach', in this case performance reasons.